# Merging branch onto trunk that does not share ancestry

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

A project that I've been pulled into in my company has been somewhat messed up in SVN (I will blame our expectation that engineers should know how to use it without prior exposure and no training).  The project was previously owned by one engineer, but ownership has been transferred to a newer hire who was more unfamiliar with how SVN works.  When he started working on the code base, he made a "branch" to work out of, but neglected to use the TortoiseSVN <kbd>Branch/tag...</kbd> command.

Instead, he simply created a directory called `Development` in the `./branches` directory and copied over all the files manually.  In the last 6 months, this branch has become what the trunk should be, and it has been used extensively without ever merging back to the trunk.  Since then, the project has had to grow in size and ability, to where there are now several new directories, files, and externals added to the `Development` branch.  We're talking about 800 revisions difference at this point.

**So how do I fix it?**

Currently, if I run through the <kbd>Merge...</kbd> command, using the <kbd>Merge a range of revisions</kbd> option, I can mess with the options in several ways but none of them pass the <kbd>Test merge</kbd> without conflicts and tree conflicts.  In particular, the conflicts occur mainly on the second commit to the `Development` "branch", and after that the conflicts likely wouldn't occur.  So far I've tried:

- <kbd>Merge a range of revisions</kbd> -> <kbd>All revisions</kbd> -> <kbd>Test merge</kbd>
- <kbd>Merge a range of revisions</kbd> -> <kbd>specific range</kbd>=`REV1-REV2` -> <kbd>Test merge</kbd>
- <kbd>Merge a range of revisions</kbd> -> <kbd>specific range</kbd>=`REV1-REV2` -> <kbd>Ignore ancestry</kbd>=`True` -> <kbd>Test merge</kbd>
- <kbd>Merge two different trees</kbd> -> <kbd>Test merge</kbd>
- <kbd>Merge two different trees</kbd> -> <kbd>Ignore ancestry</kbd>=`True` -> <kbd>Test merge</kbd>

Of these 5 combinations, the last one seems most promising in that there are only tree conflicts and they just occur on the added folders and files (the externals look like they'd be merged properly, but it's hard to tell when just using <kbd>Test merge</kbd>.

I would like to preserve history as best as possible, but at this point the code in the `trunk` is so outdated that it's useless and I wouldn't be completely opposed to just copying over it.  What would be the most painless path forward to get this "branch" moved back onto the `trunk` while preserving the maximum amount of information about what happened?

I've already talked to the developer who owns this project and we're going to be working through this problem together so that he can learn more about how SVN works and how to use it properly.  I want to come prepared so that we can complete it quickly and gain as much as we can from the experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- CLI-way in hard cases is better and more safe, than GUI
- "Merge two different trees" is for 99% of merges the bad and ugly way of reintegration merge
- Re-read carefully ["Noticing or Ignoring Ancestry"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.ancestry) from SVN Book in order to better understand internals and **A MUST** options for your case

**NotShort Resume**

In order to get `Development` state in the trunk and abandon all trunk's history from starting of `Development` you have to call (in trunk's clean WC)

`svn merge --ignore-ancestry --accept 'tf' /PATH/TO/Development`

(no merge-conflicts, *may be* tree-conflicts)

For TSVN it's

<kbd>Merge a range of revisions</kbd> -> <kbd>All revisions</kbd> (<kbd>specific range</kbd> = `empty` is equal to "All") -> <kbd>Ignore ancestry</kbd> = `True`

but you'll not be able to define automatic conflict-resolution (`--accept` option), as it can be done in CLI